# Adding sum of current_timestamp and days column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I want update a column by adding days to current time. In pseudosyntax it would be:

```
UPDATE foo
SET time = current_timestamp + days::integer
```

days is a column in the same table.

Comment: I forgot to mention that "days" is a column in the same table, not constant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create function add_days_to_timestamp(t timestamptz, d int) 
returns timestamptz
as
$$
begin
    return t + interval '1' day * d;
end; 
$$ language 'plpgsql';


create operator + (leftarg = timestamptz, rightarg = int, 
         procedure = add_days_to_timestamp);
```

Now this would work:

```
update foo set time = current_timestamp + 3 /* day variable here, 
or a column from your table */
```

**Note:**

for some reason, adding an integer to date is built-in in Postgres, this would work:

```
select current_timestamp::date + 3 -- but only a date
```

this would not(unless you define your own operator, see above):

```
select current_timestamp + 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really eye opener for what I can do with postgresql

Answer (score 8):

```
select now() + cast('1 day' as interval) * 3 -- example: 3 days
```

Comment: This was the actually exactly what I needed. I am not sure why this isn't part of your answer @Michael Buen

Answer (score 2):

calculatedDate timestamp without time zone;

```
calculatedDate := current_timestamp + interval '1' day * days_count;
```