# How to query sum previous row of the same column with with pgSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to put in column RESULT the sum of same row's column SOMETHING and previous row column SOMETHING if it is a negative number, e.g. B3 = A3 + MIN(0, B2).

I've tried using window function but got nowhere, It just show a result that it's not the expected. (month_year is DATE field)

```
group   month_year  something   result
a         jan/19        -2      -2
a         fev/19        -4      -6
a         mar/19        -6      -12
a         abr/19        60      48
a         mai/19        -2      46
a         jun/19        9       55
a         jul/19        11      66
b         jan/19        100     100
b         fev/19        -200    -100
b         mar/19        300     200
b         abr/19        -50     150
b         mai/19        30      180
b         jun/19        -88     92
b         jul/19        -86     6
```

Expected Result:

[image]

That's the result I'm looking for, if there's another way to achive that I'm all for it. Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [user-defined aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xaggr.html)

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/03ee7/1

## DDL

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (grop varchar(1), month_year text, something int)
;

INSERT INTO t
    (grop, month_year, something)
VALUES
    ('a', '201901', -2),
    ('a', '201902', -4),
    ('a', '201903', -6),
    ('a', '201904', 60),
    ('a', '201905', -2),
    ('a', '201906', 9),
    ('a', '201907', 11),
    ('b', '201901', 100),
    ('b', '201902', -200),
    ('b', '201903', 300),
    ('b', '201904', -50),
    ('b', '201905', 30),
    ('b', '201906', -88),
    ('b', '201907', -86)
;
```

## User-defined aggregate

```
create or replace function negative_accum(_accumulated_b numeric, _current_b numeric)
returns numeric as
$$
    select case when _accumulated_b < 0 then
        _accumulated_b + _current_b
    else
        _current_b
    end
$$ language 'sql';

create aggregate negative_summer(numeric)
(
    sfunc = negative_accum,
    stype = numeric,
    initcond = 0
);

select  
    *, 
  negative_summer(something) over (order by grop, month_year) as result
from t
```

The first parameter (_accumulated_b) holds the accumulated value of the column. The second parameter (_current_b) holds the value of the current row's column.

Output:

[image]

As for your pseudo-code `B3 = A3 + MIN(0, B2)`

I used this typical code:

```
select case when _accumulated_b < 0 then
    _accumulated_b + _current_b
else
    _current_b
end
```

That can be written idiomatically in Postgres as:

```
select _current_b + least(_accumulated_b, 0)
```

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/70fa8/1

```
create or replace function negative_accum(_accumulated_b numeric, _current_b numeric)
returns numeric as
$$
    select _current_b + least(_accumulated_b, 0) 
$$ language 'sql';
```

You can also use other language with accumulator function, e.g., plpgsql. Note that plpgsql (or perhaps the $$ quote) is not supported in http://sqlfiddle.com. So no live test link, this would work on your machine though:

```
create or replace function negative_accum(_accumulated_b numeric, _current_b numeric)
returns numeric as
$$begin
    return _current_b + least(_accumulated_b, 0);
end$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

**UPDATE**

I missed the `partition by`, here's an example data (changed 11 to -11) where without  `partition by` and with `partition by` would yield different results:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/87795/4

```
INSERT INTO t
    (grop, month_year, something)
VALUES
    ('a', '201901', -2),
    ('a', '201902', -4),
    ('a', '201903', -6),
    ('a', '201904', 60),
    ('a', '201905', -2),
    ('a', '201906', 9),
    ('a', '201907', -11), -- changed this from 11 to -11
    ('b', '201901', 100),
    ('b', '201902', -200),
    ('b', '201903', 300),
    ('b', '201904', -50),
    ('b', '201905', 30),
    ('b', '201906', -88),
    ('b', '201907', -86)
;
```

Output:

```
| grop | month_year | something | result_wrong | result |
|------|------------|-----------|--------------|--------|
|    a |     201901 |        -2 |           -2 |     -2 |
|    a |     201902 |        -4 |           -6 |     -6 |
|    a |     201903 |        -6 |          -12 |    -12 |
|    a |     201904 |        60 |           48 |     48 |
|    a |     201905 |        -2 |           -2 |     -2 |
|    a |     201906 |         9 |            7 |      7 |
|    a |     201907 |       -11 |          -11 |    -11 |
|    b |     201901 |       100 |           89 |    100 |
|    b |     201902 |      -200 |         -200 |   -200 |
|    b |     201903 |       300 |          100 |    100 |
|    b |     201904 |       -50 |          -50 |    -50 |
|    b |     201905 |        30 |          -20 |    -20 |
|    b |     201906 |       -88 |         -108 |   -108 |
|    b |     201907 |       -86 |         -194 |   -194 |
```

Comment: Man that looks awesome.
How does it work? How is negative_summer calling negative_accum without parameters? How is this called so I can look it up and learn more about it.
Thank you very much

Comment: It's called user-defined aggregate. negative_summer is calling negative_accum with two parameters. the first parameter (_accumulated_b) is the accumulated value, the second parameter (_current_b) is the value of the current row's column. so on first row, _accumulated_b receives initial value from initcond's value (0), _current_b receives the value from current row's column, -2. so on first row, negative_summer is calling `negative_accum(0, -2)`. then on second row, negative_summer will call `negative_accum(-2, -4)`, then on third row, `negative_accum(-6, -6)`, and so on

Comment: here's another example: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/writing-your-own-aggregation-functions/

Comment: Thank you very much.
Just so the answer is correct, you missed the partition by group.

Answer (score 0):

You probably had problems with the window function because you need to have something to order by, and your month_year column isn't going to naturally sort.  See this SQL fiddle where the column is replaced by something more like a date that will order correctly.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7a304/1/0

```
CREATE TABLE t
    ([grop] varchar(1), [month_year] varchar(6), [something] int, [result] int)

INSERT INTO t
    ([grop], [month_year], [something], [result])
VALUES
    ('a', '201901', -2, -2),
    ('a', '201902', -4, -6),
    ('a', '201903', -6, -12),
    ('a', '201904', 60, 48),
    ('a', '201905', -2, -2),
    ('a', '201906', 9, 7),
    ('a', '201907', 11, 11),
    ('b', '201901', 100, 100),
    ('b', '201902', -200, -200),
    ('b', '201903', 300, 100),
    ('b', '201904', -50, -50),
    ('b', '201905', 30, -20),
    ('b', '201906', -88, -108),
    ('b', '201907', -86, -194)

select
  grop, month_year, something, result,
  sum(something) over (partition by grop order by grop, month_year) as rtot
from
  t

| grop | month_year | something | result | rtot |
|------|------------|-----------|--------|------|
|    a |     201901 |        -2 |     -2 |   -2 |
|    a |     201902 |        -4 |     -6 |   -6 |
|    a |     201903 |        -6 |    -12 |  -12 |
|    a |     201904 |        60 |     48 |   48 |
|    a |     201905 |        -2 |     -2 |   46 |
|    a |     201906 |         9 |      7 |   55 |
|    a |     201907 |        11 |     11 |   66 |
|    b |     201901 |       100 |    100 |  100 |
|    b |     201902 |      -200 |   -200 | -100 |
|    b |     201903 |       300 |    100 |  200 |
|    b |     201904 |       -50 |    -50 |  150 |
|    b |     201905 |        30 |    -20 |  180 |
|    b |     201906 |       -88 |   -108 |   92 |
|    b |     201907 |       -86 |   -194 |    6 |
```

The other part of the problem is resetting the running total when you get to a positive number.  I'm not sure if you can do that in SQL, without dropping into a stored proc, but perhaps with a clearer example someone knowledgeable will chime in.

Comment: Well actually that sum with window function I'd gotten, but as you said it needs do be resetted when it gets to zero. How would I do that using a stored proc? If it works then it's fine by me !